# Fastest way to refer to np.array elements that meet certain conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have some troubles with numpy arrays of many dimensions. Let's take a generic one, and call it A. Without be too specific, I would like to do, in the most efficient way, these following things:

1) A[A>0] = something

2) Suppose I have another multidimensional numpy array with only 1s or 0s as values, say I, and suppose it has the proper shape. I would like to say something like A[I] = something

I am aware that these expressions already work, if the dimensions are right, but I think they are not efficient enough.

Comment: In what way do you think they are not efficient enough?

Comment: Maybe I should have said "I hope there Is a more efficient way"

Comment: In order to know if an entry fulfills a condition you  have to check if it does. There is no way around doing that.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to improve the implementation of how that check is performed but you would have to look into the numpy source code for that.

Comment: if and elseif ?